# Simple math/programming question. Individual percentage from total

Tags: math, lua

I'm no good at math. :) Is this right?

I'm accumulating all CPU seconds, and I need to find what percentage the addon's CPU time is from the total.

```
function PluginResources.GetTotalCPU(addon)
    UpdateAddOnCPUUsage()
    local totalCPU = 0
    for i=1, GetNumAddOns() do
        totalCPU = totalCPU + (GetAddOnCPUUsage(i) )
    end 
    local addonUsage = GetAddOnCPUUsage(addon)
    local usage = totalCPU / addonUsage
    return usage
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `usage = addonUsage / totalCPU`.